# How to get table from Wikipedia

Tags: c#, xml, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I want to put one table from Wikipedia into xml file and then parse it to C#. Is it possible? If yes, can I save in xml only **Title** and **Genre** column?

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_in_film");

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='wikitable']");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a web browser:

```
//First navigate to your address
 webBrowser1.Navigate("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_in_film");
        List<string> Genre = new List<string>();
        List<string> Title = new List<string>();
  //When page loaded
  foreach (HtmlElement table in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table"))
            {
                if (table.GetAttribute("className").Equals("wikitable"))
                {
                    foreach (HtmlElement tr in table.GetElementsByTagName("tr"))
                    {
                        int columncount = 1;
                        foreach (HtmlElement td in tr.GetElementsByTagName("td"))
                        {
                            //Title
                            if (columncount == 4)
                            {
                                Title.Add(td.InnerText);
                            }
                            //Genre
                            if (columncount == 7)
                            {
                                Genre.Add(td.InnerText);
                            }
                            columncount++;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

now you have two list (genre and title).
you can simply convert them to xml file

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:
Search for the html tag which you want to search for and make a regular expression to parse the rest of the data.
This code will search for the table which has width 150 and gets all the url/nav url's.

```
HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table"); //get collection in link
                {
                    foreach (HtmlElement link_data in links) //parse for each collection
                    {
                        String width = link_data.GetAttribute("width");
                        {
                            if (width != null && width == "150")
                            {
                                Regex linkX = new Regex("<a[^>]*?href=\"(?<href>[\\s\\S]*?)\"[^>]*?>(?<Title>[\\s\\S]*?)</a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                                MatchCollection category_urls = linkX.Matches(link_data.OuterHtml);
                                if (category_urls.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (Match match in category_urls)
                                    {
                                           //rest of the code
                                    }
                                }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also consider looking at the Wikipedia API to zero in on a particular section of a wikipedia page

- https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=2012_in_film&mobileformat=html&section=1&prop=wikitext

The API documentation describes how you can format the search results for subsequent parsing.